# Magallanes deployment tool PHP

Tags: php, deployment

I use Magallanes to deploy my projects, and the problem that I have is how can I catch the errors during a deployment, for example when I throw a command to create the database, this already exist.

And other is how can I return personalized messages from the tasks, example

```
<?php
namespace Task;

use Mage\Task\AbstractTask;

class AssignPermissions extends AbstractTask
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Asignando permisos ' . $this->getParameter('permission','') . ' a la carpeta ' . $this->getParameter('target','');
    }

    public function run()
    { 
        $permission = $this->getParameter('permission','');
        $target = $this->getParameter('target','');

        if($permission == '' AND $target == '')
        {
            return false;
        }

        $result = $this->runCommandRemote('chmod ' . $permission . ' ' . $target);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

If the permission parameter is empty, return "The permission is required"

Thanks and regards!